# Steps to fix charset encoding on mariadb database

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, mariadb

I created a mariadb database in a Docker container and then copied some data from an older version of the application, by using SQuirreL's "Create Data Script" operation, which generates a bunch of "INSERT INTO" statements.  This all worked fine and we've been writing new data into the database for a few weeks.

Yesterday someone reported an error trying to save new data, and from the log I found this:

```
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x95\x09Onb...' for column 'ssimpact' at row 1
```

I determined that the text they were trying to save had "bullet" characters copied from an email they received in Outlook.  I tried a similar test, creating a bullet in a MS Word doc and copying it into the text field and trying to save it, which produced the same error.

So, I apparently have a character encoding problem.  The user has a workaround, to simply replace bullet characters with asterisks, but I'd like to avoid the need for this workaround.

I noticed when I ran "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA" in SQuirreL, it showed that the charset and collation for my database was "latin1" and "latin1_swedish_ci", but there was also the "information_schema" database, with "utf8" and "utf8_general_ci".

Did I need to create this database with "utf8" and "utf8_general_ci" to avoid this problem?

Assuming that was the case, and that I don't want to recreate the database and recopy all of the data, if I do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf-8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

For all the tables that might get these "special" characters, will that resolve this?  Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: `C29509` does not register as anything obvious.  Was the the original hex, or did you do some form of ALTER before?  Can you provide another sample?  Can you say what it should say?  In latin1, 95 is a bullet, but then the c2 and 09 don't make sense.

Comment: I just created a blank msword doc, put it into bullet mode, entered "abcd", carriage return, efgh, then copied that doc and pasted it into my web form and saved that. That resulted in " org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x95\x09Abc...' for column 'ssimpact' at row 1".

Comment: Export as plain ascii, not rich document (.doc)

Comment: Your suggestion is that I tell the users that they simply can't paste directly from a msword doc into the form. I need a better solution than that.

Comment: Well, if you declare things to be `latin1`, it will be closer:  `Â•` and a tab.  I don't know why Word has the `Â` (C2).

Comment: I'm getting back to this again. I still don't have a clear path forward to fixing this.